# I don't know how to use JPQL [AND] and [OR]

Tags: java, jpql

I made application what it will be able to search book of name and author.I use JPQL to realize it.When I fill two textbox(name of book and author),it search right.But I fill one textbox,it search not found.
How to fix？

Book.java

```
@Table(name = "books")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "searchNameAndAuthor", query = "SELECT b FROM Book AS b WHERE b.book_name =:book_name and b.author=:author"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "searchNameAndAuthorCount", query = "SELECT count(b) FROM Book AS b WHERE b.book_name =:book_name and b.author=:author")
})
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "isbn_code", length = 17)
    private Integer isbn_code;

    @Column(name = "book_name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String book_name;

    @Column(name = "author", length = 20)
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "publisher", length = 20)
    private String publisher;

    @Column(name = "publish_date", length = 8)
    private Date publish_date;

    @Column(name = "stock", length = 4)
    private Integer stock;
```

search.jsp

```
<c:import url="/WEB-INF/views/layout/app.jsp">
    <c:param name="content">
        <c:if test="${flush != null}">
            <div id="flush_success">
                <c:out value="${flush}"></c:out>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <h2>図書館ようこそ</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="<c:url value='/books/search/result' />">
            <label for="book_name">調べたいタイトル</label><br /> <input type="text"
                name="book_name" value="${book_name}" /> <br />
            <br />
            <label for="author">著者</label><br /> <input type="text"
                name="author" value="${author}" /> <br />
            <br />
            <button type="submit">検索</button>
        </form>
    </c:param>
</c:import>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the null case also. A way can be checking is the parameter is null as OR condition

```
SELECT b FROM Book AS b WHERE (:book_name IS NULL OR b.book_name =:book_name) 
                          and (:author IS NULL OR  b.author=:author)
```

Comment: I can select data from database. I am very grateful!

Comment: How to write equivalent criteria query using CriteriaBuilder?